# Full-text search contains NEAR had problem with "\n" , EOL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I used SQL Server full-text search but I had problem with `CONTAINS NEAR` query.

When I use `... CONTAINS(column_name, 'NEAR((John, 1999), 30)')` in text query without `"\n"` like that

> ....xxx John Jacob Smith 1999

its OK.

but if the text query has "\n"

> ....xxx John Jacob Smith
> 1999.

It's not found by the query above

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066496/sql-server-2008-line-break-and-fulltext-queries

Answer (score 0):

### NEAR() Search Term Distance Calculation

You need to increase the allowed distance number between your search terms of "John" and "1999". Your query example uses 30 which means 30 "terms" can be between John and 1999. But line breaks "equals" 128 terms.

For the line break example data, the gap is 130 from "John" to "1999"

```
+ 1 for "Jacob"
+ 1 for "Smith"
+ 128 for line break
= 130
```

See quote about paragraph (line break) from Microsoft's doc on NEAR() full doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/search-for-words-close-to-another-word-with-near?view=sql-server-ver15)

> If a match spans the end of a sentence, paragraph, or chapter, the gap
> used for ranking a document is increased by 8, 128, or 1024,
> respectively.

### SQL Script Example

```
/*Returns only the 1 row without a line break*/
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS(YourCol, 'NEAR((John, 1999), 129)')

/*Returns both rows*/
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS(YourCol, 'NEAR((John, 1999), 130)') /*Increased max distance to 130*/
```